# WordPress pagination not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

WordPress pagination not working after first wp_query. I am performing some operations on the data returned by first wp_query object. but after the second query, pagination is not working.

```
<?php

    $prop_no      =   intval( get_option('wp_estate_prop_no', '') );
    $paged        = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array(
            'post_type'        =>  'estate_property',
            'author'           =>  $current_user->ID,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'posts_per_page'    => $prop_no,
            'post_status'      =>  array( 'any' ),              
        );

    $prop_selection = new WP_Query($args);

    //some code

    $args = array(
            'post_type'        =>  'estate_property',
            'author'           =>  $current_user->ID,
            'paged'             => $paged,
            'posts_per_page'    => $prop_no,
            'post__in'         =>  $sorted_posts,
            'orderby'          => 'post__in'

        );


    $prop_selection = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

I tried removing the 'paged' parameter from one of the queries, that gives either wrong results or no pagination. ex. this query returns 28 results first time but only returns 6 results after second query. And if I remove the 'paged' parameter from first query and add it to second query then only one page is returned when it should return 3 pages.

Comment: `wp_reset_postdata()` should be used after every custom `new WP_Query()`.

Comment: I have used it before second query, but still not returning correct result

Comment: It happen cause pagination use main query, If you are in custom page or custom archive, please take a look my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36526482).

Answer (score 0):

Create Function in `function.php`

```
function sofg_pagination($max_num_pages,$paged,$page_id){
    if($max_num_pages > 1){
    echo '<div class="post-wrap pgns">';
    echo '<ul class="pagination_list">';
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page_id).'page/1">First</a></li>';
    for($i=1; $i<= $max_num_pages; $i++){
        if($paged==$i){ 
            echo '<li class="active"><a href="'.get_permalink($page_id).'page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }
        else{ echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page_id).'page/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>'; }
    }
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($page_id).'page/'.$max_num_pages.'">Last</a></li>';
    echo '</ul></div>';
    }
}
```

Get Pagination Your `listing page`

**Define Before loop**

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$page_id = get_the_ID();
```

**Use After Loop**

```
$max_num_pages_1 = $max_num_pages->max_num_pages;
sofg_pagination($max_num_pages_1,$paged,$page_id);
```

[image]

See pagination http://hiddenwhy.igexsolutions.com/blog/

Comment: I have the pagination function and it works for other cases (On this page also if I remove the second query).